# How to compile .java with dependencies on runtime?

Tags: java, compilation, dependencies, runtime, javacompiler

I have a lot of `.java` files that need to import another `.java` file...

Something like this:

```
import package.c;

public class A {

  // do whatever that needs package.c
}
```

But I only have the `package.c.java`.

When I try to compile Using Java Compiler or anything else that I know, i always got these errors

> error: package <-package-> does not exist

Or something like:

> error: cannot find symbol

I can't compile `A.java` because need `C.class` that can't be compiled cause need another one, someone know what should I do?

Everything is ok when the `.java` doesn't need dependencies, in these cases Java Compiler do well.

Maybe [GetStarted](https://code.google.com/archive/p/compilation-toolbox/wikis/GetStarted.wiki) link could resolve my problem, but i can't find a way to do this.

[EDIT]  That is my compiler code:

```
    File sourceDir = new File(source);
    JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
    DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();
    StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, Locale.getDefault(), null);
    List<JavaFileObject> javaObjects = scanRecursivelyForJavaObjects(sourceDir, fileManager);
    System.out.println(javaObjects.size());
    if (javaObjects.size() == 0) {
        throw new CompilationError("There are no source files to compile in " + sourceDir.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    String[] compileOptions = new String[]{"-d", sourceDir.getAbsolutePath()};
    Iterable<String> compilationOptions = Arrays.asList(compileOptions);

    CompilationTask compilerTask = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, diagnostics, compilationOptions, null, javaObjects);

    if (!compilerTask.call()) {            
        for (Diagnostic<?> diagnostic : diagnostics.getDiagnostics()) {
            System.err.format("Error on line %d in %s", diagnostic.getLineNumber(), diagnostic);
        }
        throw new CompilationError("Could not compile project");
    }
```

where I give a path and find all .java files in there , adding them in a list and trying to compile all at same time.

Comment: show the command line you use to compile your code

Comment: Compile all the files at the same time?

Comment: You will need to have the dependencies available at compile time in the classpath, either as the source, compiled as class files or packaged in a Jar library

Comment: @MadProgrammer i know that i need to have the dependencies avaliable, but everything that i have are the .java files, and i don't know how to compile all of them at same time.

Comment: You can pass all the .java files to `javac` in single command, but you will need to do it the correct order

Answer (score 1):

javaDoc was a little bit usefull : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html

mainlly this :

JavaCompiler.CompilationTask getTask(Writer out,
                                   JavaFileManager fileManager,
                                   DiagnosticListener diagnosticListener,
                                   Iterable options,
                                   Iterable classes,
                                   Iterable compilationUnits)

*Parameters:*

- out - a Writer for additional output from the compiler; use System.err if null
- fileManager - a file manager; if null use the compiler's standard filemanager
- diagnosticListener - a diagnostic listener; if null use the compiler's default method for reporting diagnostics
- classes - names of classes to be processed by annotation processing, null means no class names
- options - compiler options, null means no options
- compilationUnits - the compilation units to compile, null means no compilation units

so .....

I opened a project with the follwing

```
package compileTest1;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.tools.Diagnostic;
import javax.tools.DiagnosticCollector;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler.CompilationTask;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.StandardJavaFileManager;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;


public class MyCompiler {

private File classesDir;
private File sourceDir;

public void loadClassesFromCompiledDirectory() throws Exception {
    new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{classesDir.toURI().toURL()});
}

public void compile() throws Exception {
    JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
    DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();
    StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, Locale.getDefault(), null);
    List<JavaFileObject> javaObjects = scanRecursivelyForJavaObjects(sourceDir, fileManager);

    if (javaObjects.size() == 0) {
        throw new Exception("There are no source files to compile in " + sourceDir.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    String[] compileOptions = new String[]{"-d", classesDir.getAbsolutePath()} ;
    Iterable<String> compilationOptions = Arrays.asList(compileOptions);

    CompilationTask compilerTask = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, diagnostics, compilationOptions, null, javaObjects) ;

    if (!compilerTask.call()) {
        for (Diagnostic<?> diagnostic : diagnostics.getDiagnostics()) {
            System.err.format("Error on line %d in %s", diagnostic.getLineNumber(), diagnostic);
        }
        throw new Exception("Could not compile project");
    }
}

private List<JavaFileObject> scanRecursivelyForJavaObjects(File dir, StandardJavaFileManager fileManager) {
    List<JavaFileObject> javaObjects = new LinkedList<JavaFileObject>();
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            javaObjects.addAll(scanRecursivelyForJavaObjects(file, fileManager));
        }
        else if (file.isFile() && file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".java")) {
            javaObjects.add(readJavaObject(file, fileManager));
        }
    }
    return javaObjects;
}


private JavaFileObject readJavaObject(File file, StandardJavaFileManager fileManager) {
    Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> javaFileObjects = fileManager.getJavaFileObjects(file);
    Iterator<? extends JavaFileObject> it = javaFileObjects.iterator();
    if (it.hasNext()) {
        return it.next();
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Could not load " + file.getAbsolutePath() + " java file object");
}

public File getClassesDir() {
    return classesDir;
}

public void setClassesDir(File classesDir) {
    this.classesDir = classesDir;
}

public File getSourceDir() {
    return sourceDir;
}

public void setSourceDir(File sourceDir) {
    this.sourceDir = sourceDir;
}
}
```

took from https://github.com/ishubin/blogix/blob/master/src/main/java/net/mindengine/blogix/compiler/BlogixCompiler.java

The main method is :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyCompiler compiler = new MyCompiler();
    compiler.setClassesDir(new File(".")); 
    compiler.setSourceDir(new File("C:\\Users\\...\\workspace\\compileTest\\src\\objectA"));
    try {
        compiler.compile();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**The ObjectA recived ObjectB in his c'tor, so we know A depend on B,**
**to be sure I tried to complie ObjectA with javac in the cmd and got errors**

the errors I got in the cmd :
[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBPRR.png)

The structur of the project :
[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlsSK.png)

one more thing, I set classesDir to file with the path "." so the .class file of the compiled java files will be stored in the bin folder of the project.

**work just find also when the .java files are in two different packages :**
[img3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIsxc.png)

the only change I did was in classesDir value to  -> "... \compileTest\bin"

Comment: But i want to load into existing load class (Build compiled class)how can we do that ?